# Select range (limit) of results in Oracle SQL / pagination

Tags: sql, oracle, pagination, rows

Let's say we have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE "ARTICLE_COUNTER_STATISTICS_M"
(
  "ID"        NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
  "ITEMCOUNT" NUMBER(19,0),
  "VERSION" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP
)
```

Unique constraint is on ID and VERSION field.

Example of some rows that could be in DB(Timestamps is be the same for all records always):

```
1374659422641   22  2014.02.26 09:45:01,000000000
1387797258001   7   2014.02.26 09:45:01,000000000
1387796687862   1   2014.02.26 09:45:01,000000000
1387800521317   1   2014.02.26 09:45:01,000000000
```

Now, if we want to select the IDs, itemcount and order them by itemcount we would be doing something like this:

```
SELECT id, SUM(itemcount) as count, version 
FROM ARTICLE_COUNTER_STATISTICS_m 
WHERE id != '0' 
GROUP BY id, version 
ORDER BY version DESC, SUM(itemcount) DESC
```

But the thing that is unclear, how do we select results only in certain range. For example 10 to 20 items with most count? I tried something like this:

```
SELECT id, count, version FROM( 
    SELECT id, SUM(itemcount) as count, version 
    FROM ARTICLE_COUNTER_STATISTICS_m 
    WHERE id != '0' 
    GROUP BY id, version 
    ORDER BY version DESC, SUM(itemcount) DESC 
) where rownum >= 0 and rownum <= 20
```

But it does not work with if n in "where rownum >= n" is greater than 1 (it just returns empty results). I know that probably ROW_NUMBER() function has to be used to accomplish the goal, but I could not get it working. Any ideas? Thx!

Comment: Not related to your question, but using "WHERE id != '0' " is going to hurt your performance badly - Oracle will convert the ID column to a string to do the comparison. Use "WHERE id != 0 " instead (without the quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `row_number` example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT id, itemcount, version, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY version DESC, itemcount DESC) AS rn
        FROM   (SELECT id, SUM(itemcount) as itemcount, version 
                FROM ARTICLE_COUNTER_STATISTICS_m 
                WHERE id != '0' 
                GROUP BY id, version
               )
        )
WHERE  rn BETWEEN 3 AND 20 -- just an example
```

Note that `row_number` assigns arbitrary order to items with the same properties (as per the window clause). So, if for example, your first three items all have `version=100` and `itemcount=100` and you use `rn BETWEEN 2 AND 4`, there's no telling which one will be excluded. To avoid this, you can use `rank`, which assigns the same value to items of the same properties (again, as defined by the window clause).

Comment: Thank you, this also works (count on line 2 has to be changed to itemcount though, I couldn't edit your post). But if I replace ROW_NUMBER() with RANK(), it gives me incorrect results on 2 to 5, for example. Is there any thing else I have to modify for it to work with rank?

Comment: Re: `count` vs. `itemcount` - fixed, thanks for noticing. Re: wrong results with `rank` - as I mentioned, items with the same properties will have the same value, so you may get a bit more/less items than you bargained for (but at least it'll be deterministic). Can you give a specific example where it did not act as planned?

Comment: Nevermind, it was working correct. It's just that when using rownum example provided by Dba indexing starts from 0, but with ROW_NUMBER() or RANK() starts from 1. Thank you both, Mureinik and Dba for the great answers! :) I would like to mark both as accepted answers, but I have to choose one :(. I will choose Mureinik's, since I gave vote up for Dba already. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT a.*, rownum rn
    FROM(
        SELECT id, SUM(itemcount) as count, version 
        FROM   ARTICLE_COUNTER_STATISTICS_m 
        WHERE  id != 0
        GROUP BY id, version 
        ORDER BY VERSION DESC, SUM(itemcount) DESC
          ) a
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 20
    )
WHERE rn > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Any ideas what was wrong with my example and why did it not work? Could ROW_NUMBER() have been used instead?

Comment: @Javatar, Yes, You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` too to get this, but it is quite inefficient in `ORACLE`. Refer the below link to know the difference b/w `ROWNUM` and `ROW_NUMBER`. http://explainextended.com/2009/05/06/oracle-row_number-vs-rownum/