# Query for doing pagination in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, pagination

I have a query in mysql to do pagination using start index and no of records per page, the query is

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT STARTINDEX, PAGESIZE.
```

This is working really fine with a MySQL database. But I have to do same thing with an Oracle database.

However, this query is does not work in Oracle. Can someone give a query which works in Oracle using start index and page size?

There are other questions which has taken many conditions but I want to use only start index and  page size  options.

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: can you provide link to that question..

Comment: The link is added automatically to your question.

Comment: There it was taken many conditions but I want to build a query only using start index and page size...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing how that is a different question.  You'd just need to compute the end row based on the start row and the page size.

Comment: Take a look at this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035165/select-range-limit-of-results-in-oracle-sql-pagination